# Dnlib как заменяются int переменные?

Tags: c#, dnlib

Пробую так найти строку: `int num = 10;`

```
if (instruction.OpCode == OpCodes.Ldc_I4_S)
{
   instr[i].Operand = Convert.ToInt32("100"); // Пробую заменить
}
```

Но не получается.
Как изменяются `int`, `double`, `uint` и прочие численные ?

Comment: А в чем смысл этого кода? Зачем преобразовывать строковую константу 100 в Int32? И какой тип имеет в DnLib свойство Operand?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, инструкция `ldc.i4.s` и `box System.Int32` в коде записано так: `int num = 10` На счёт зачем преобразовывать: Это просто для теста, оставил уже так как есть, потому что не знаю как её заменить.